# How can non-final variables be switch constants?

Tags: java, switch-statement, constants, final

```
public class SwitchTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer i = new Integer(2) + new Integer(2);

    switch(i){
      case 4: System.out.println("foo"); break;
      default: System.out.println("default"); break;
    }
  }
}
```

Integer i is not marked as final. (I'm only a beginner in java.)

Comment: `i` isn't a "switch constant" here, it's the variable being switched on. It'll switch on the current value, just like an `if`.

Comment: Switch parameters do not have to be final. something is not correct in your environment.

Comment: You can also write: `switch(new Random().nextInt())` without any problem. But you cannot write `case new Random().nextInt():`, because each `case` needs a *compile-time constant*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confusing `case` labels with `switch` operands.

There is nothing wrong with `switch`ing on a non-constant value; in fact, without that, `switch` would be mostly useless.